# Is it possible to set Position property for TextBox in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, textbox, ms-word

I generate TextBox in my macro. I would like to set its position to `square` or `through` so it is not behind the text. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering continuation of your other question you could set `textbox position` in one of these ways:

```
Dim Box As Shape
Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=100)

Box.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapThrough
Box.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
```